# ArrayList not adding objects?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have a piece of code:

```
public void setBoardMemberPosition() {

    int[] position = null;

    do{
        positionX = RandomNumberGenerator.generateRandomNumber(Board.DIMENSION);
        positionY = RandomNumberGenerator.generateRandomNumber(Board.DIMENSION);

        position = new int[] { positionX, positionY };


    } while(checkIfPositionIsOccupied(position));

    board.setElementAt(positionX, positionY, name);
    storedMembers.add(position);

}
```

Can someone explain to me why the elements are not being added to the list, where:

`private ArrayList<int[]> storedMembers = new ArrayList<int[]>();`is a Class variable and:`checkIfPositionIsOccupied(position)` returns true/false

`if (storedMembers.contains(position))`

i have a feeling its something to do with the `do while`, ive debugged it with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the array `position` to the `ArrayList` on each iteration, your `add()` call must be inside the loop:

```
do {
    // ...

    storedMembers.add(position);
} while(...);
```

**Edit:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < storedMembers.size(); i ++)
    // ...

    if (!checkIfPositionIsOccupied(position))
        storedMembers.add(position);
}
```

Comment: But i dont need it to be on each itteration, just if `checkIfPositionIsOccupied(position)` returns false. thats why i initalised the variable before the loop??

Comment: Then you can add a condition inside the loop. The check `checkIfPositionIsOccupied(position)` shouldn't be loop condition. But you will have to think **how many iterations** there would be?

Comment: so i should probably use a for loop of `storedMembers.size()` itterations?

Comment: Yes, in that case a `for` loop will be better. See edit.

Comment: Ok ill try it that way, but it still dosent clear up the original problem... im not understanding it atall, ive even tried adding it to the list int the `checkIfPositionIsOccupied(position)` method with no luck...

Comment: It should be fine if inside a loop, you check `if (!checkIfPositionIsOccupied(position))` it that method returns `false`, then `!false` will evaluate to `true`. If the condition is `true`, then add the array to `storedMembers`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't add in your while loop anything to the list?!